# Hadoop Jar FileSystemNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce, nio

I am running a hadoop cluster and attempting to run a mapreduce job using a jar file I send to the cluster. The problem is that on certain nodes it succeeds and others it fails. The error I am seeing on certain nodes is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:183)
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:169)
        at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:154)
        at customLib.readFile(CustomClass2.java:254)
        at customLib.access$000(CustomClass2.java:210)
        at customLib.getFieldOrder(CustomClass2.java:591)
        at customLib.run(CustomClass1.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
        at customLib.main(CustomClass1.java:136)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

I see that others have had similar problems such as this questions with solutions and links to other questions and soltuions: [java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException when getting file from resources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746667/java-nio-file-filesystemnotfoundexception-when-getting-file-from-resources-folde/29747012). However, none of these solutions could explain why it would work on one node and not another... this must mean there is some config I have wrong somewhere.

I have checked all the hadoop xml config files as well as the $CLASSPATH, $PATH, and java runtime version and everything seems to be the same. If anyone has any other ideas on what I could check, that would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

EDIT: To clarify, the file it is trying to get is a resource that is packaged within the JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607953/7969573. It looks like the nodes that were failing had a copy of the jar with the class I was running in the #HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/ folder which was in my CLASSPATH. Deleting the jar from the nodes fixed the issue as I run the jar from a shell invoked by my application. I could have just updated that jar and it would have worked as well, but it made more sense to delete it under my current workflow's architecture.